# Thrust copy - OutputIterator column-major order

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have a vector of matrices (stored as column major arrays) that I want to concat vertically. Therefore, I want to utilize the copy function from the thrust framework as in the following example snippet:

```
int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i) {
    thrust::copy(
        thrust::device_ptr<float>(matrices[i]),
        thrust::device_ptr<float>(matrices[i]) + rows[i] * cols[i],
        thrust::device_ptr<float>(result) + offset
    );

    offset += rows[i] * cols[i];
}
```

EDIT: extended example:

The problem is, that if I have a matrix A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] (2 rows, 3 cols; in memory [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]) and another B = [[7, 8, 9]] (1 row, 3 cols; in memory [7, 8, 9]), the resulting matrix C is not [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] (3 row, 3 cols; in memory [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]), but [[1, 5, 7], [4, 3, 8], [2, 6, 9]] (3 row, 3 cols; in memory [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]).

Is there an way to create an special OutputIterator for this problem (I have searched for it, but found nothing), or a fast alternative way?

EDIT: SSCCE

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

void printMat2d(thrust::device_vector<float>& mat, int rows, int cols) {
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            std::cout << mat[row + col * rows] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void printMat1d(thrust::device_vector<float>& mat, int rows, int cols) {
    for(int idx = 0; idx < cols*rows; ++idx) {
            std::cout << mat[idx] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void generateMat(thrust::device_vector<float>& mat, int rows, int cols, int add) {
    thrust::host_vector<float> matHost(rows * cols);
    int val = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            matHost[row + col * rows] = val + add;
            val++;
        }
    }
    mat = matHost;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> rows(2);
    rows[0] = 2;
    rows[1] = 3;
    std::vector<int> cols(2);
    cols[0] = 3;
    cols[1] = 3;

    //generate matrices
    std::vector<thrust::device_vector<float> > matrices(2);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i) {
        generateMat(matrices[i], rows[i], cols[i], i*10);

        std::cout << "mat_ " << i << " = " << std::endl;
        printMat2d(matrices[i], rows[i], cols[i]);
        printMat1d(matrices[i], rows[i], cols[i]);
    }

    //copy
    int resultRows = 5;
    int resultCols = 3;
    thrust::device_vector<float> result(resultRows * resultCols);
    int offset = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i) {
        thrust::copy(
            matrices[i].begin(),
            matrices[i].end(),
            result.begin() + offset
        );

        offset += rows[i] * cols[i];
    }

    std::cout << "result = " << std::endl;
    printMat2d(result, resultRows, resultCols);
    printMat1d(result, resultRows, resultCols);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a short complete example that illustrates what you are trying to achieve? Are you actually wanting to do the equivalent of a matrix transform (ie. reorder from column major to row major) during the copy operation?

Comment: I extended the example above. The problem is, that I want to vertically concat/stack two or more matrices into the _result_ matrix. Therefore, I copy the first matrix into _result_ and so on, but because the matrices are stored in column major format, the result has an false order.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example.  Something that I can copy, compile, and run, without me having to add anything or change anything.  SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "1.Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: A sscce is now provided.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I've replaced my previous answer that used the strided range per row method, with a slightly different approach, that gets the copy operation down to a single thrust call (per matrix to be copied).

The key idea here was to use a functor that converts row-major *memory* indexing to column-major *memory* indexing.  This functor can then be used with a `counting_iterator` to create arbitrary row-major to column major memory indices (via `make_transform_iterator`).  These indices can then be used in a `permutation_iterator` for the source matrix to select the element to be copied and a `permutation_iterator` for the destination matrix to select the memory position to copy to.  For a general review of `transform_iterator`, `counting_iterator`, and `permutation_iterator`, refer to the [thrust quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).  I happened to be using CUDA 5.0 and thrust 1.5.3 for this exercise.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>

struct rm2cm_idx_functor : public thrust::unary_function<int, int>
{
  int r;
  int c;

  rm2cm_idx_functor(int _r, int _c) : r(_r), c(_c) {};

  __host__ __device__
  int operator() (int idx)  {
    unsigned my_r = idx/c;
    unsigned my_c = idx%c;
    return (my_c * r) + my_r;
  }
};

typedef float my_type;


void printMat2d(thrust::device_vector<my_type>& mat, int rows, int cols) {
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            std::cout << mat[row + col * rows] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void printMat1d(thrust::device_vector<my_type>& mat, int rows, int cols) {
    for(int idx = 0; idx < cols*rows; ++idx) {
            std::cout << mat[idx] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void generateMat(thrust::device_vector<my_type>& mat, int rows, int cols, int add) {
    thrust::host_vector<my_type> matHost(rows * cols);
    int val = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            matHost[row + col * rows] = val + add;
            val++;
        }
    }
    mat = matHost;
}


void copyMat(thrust::device_vector<my_type>& src, thrust::device_vector<my_type>& dst, unsigned src_rows, unsigned src_cols, unsigned dst_rows, unsigned offset){
   thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(src.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), rm2cm_idx_functor(src_rows, src_cols))), src_rows*src_cols, thrust::make_permutation_iterator(dst.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(offset), rm2cm_idx_functor(dst_rows, src_cols))));
}



int main() {
    std::vector<int> rows(2);
    rows[0] = 2;
    rows[1] = 3;
    std::vector<int> cols(2);
    cols[0] = 3;
    cols[1] = 3;

    //generate matrices
    std::vector<thrust::device_vector<my_type> > matrices(2);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i) {
        generateMat(matrices[i], rows[i], cols[i], i*10);

        std::cout << "mat_ " << i << " = " << std::endl;
        printMat2d(matrices[i], rows[i], cols[i]);
        printMat1d(matrices[i], rows[i], cols[i]);
    }

    //copy
    int resultRows = 5;
    int resultCols = 3;
    thrust::device_vector<my_type> result(resultRows * resultCols);
    int offset = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < matrices.size(); ++i) {
      copyMat(matrices[i], result, rows[i], cols[i], resultRows, offset);
      offset += rows[i]*cols[i];
    }


    std::cout << "result = " << std::endl;
    printMat2d(result, resultRows, resultCols);
    printMat1d(result, resultRows, resultCols);

    return 0;
}
```

This also assumes that source columns == destination columns, which seems to be implicit in your problem statement.  Standard caveat: not saying this is bug free, but it seems to work for the test case built into the original problem statement.

This approach can probably still be further improved.  Right now both the read operation and the write operation associated with the `thrust::copy_n` call will be uncoalesced.  We can further improve this by making one of these two operations coalesced.  This would necessitate combining the effect of index conversion functor for both read and write into a single mapping functor, which takes into account both source and destination dimensions.  With a single mapping functor, the first term of the `copy_n` call could be just the source vector. I think it should also be possible to alternatively use `thrust::gather` or `thrust::scatter`.  However, I haven't fully worked it out.

Comment: Without testing it, I would argue that it is slower then a very simple, self-written kernel, because of the repeated kernel launches / copy calls? Is there no way to write an OutputIterator?

Comment: Further, yes I meant concatenating vertically. I corrected that in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it would be slower than a custom kernel.  I think it will be a lot faster than the code you have shown, especially for large matrices.  I didn't say there was no way to do it with a single copy call, I simply said I hadn't figured it out yet.  Perhaps someone else will have ideas.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a new method that gets the copy operation down to a single call (to `thrust::copy_n`) per source matrix to be copied.