# Thrust Sort by key on the fly or different approach?

Tags: c++, sorting, cuda, thrust

I was wondering if it is possible to sort by keys using Thrust Library without the need of creating a Vector to store the keys (on the fly). For example I have the following two vectors: Keys and Values:

```
vectorKeys:    0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  2 

VectorValues: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90
```

After sort by keys:

```
thrust::sort_by_key(vKeys.begin(), vKeys.end(), vValues.begin());
```

The Resulting vectors are:

```
vectorKeys:    0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2 

VectorValues: 10, 40, 70, 20, 50, 80, 30, 60, 90
```

What I would like to know if it is possible to sort_by_key without the need of the vKeys vector (on the fly), so I can save memory of storing it and be able to sort more data?

At the end, I want to sum by the same keys and storing in a vector... is there a better approach instead of sort by key and later reduce by key to get the same result?

```
FinalVector = 120, 150, 180
```

Comment: I have 0 experience with Thrust, but in normal CPU code, I'd use a procedural iterator for the keys - one which computes the key in `operator *`.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be the case that you know a relationship between the key values and data values a priori? And if you do know that relationship, then isn't it also the case that you don't actually need to sort at all, just perform a gather operation?

Comment: Thanks Angew and Talonmies for your answers!

Talonmies, I do not know exactly how to use this gather operation with thrust... The reason why I am doing this sort by keys is that later after sorting the values. I want to sum all the values using reduce_by_key using sum_rows.cu approach, in which is not necessary to use an input array that was previously stored.

Comment: I do not know if there is a strategy instead of sort_by_key and later reduce_by_key... In which I can sum the values in key index: 0,4,7. 1,5,8 and finally 2,6,9. Maybe using counting_iterator for this sequence... but I could not manage to do it...

Comment: The example in your last comment does not match the example in your post. If you want to reduce the elements with the non-sorted key indices `(0,4,7)`, then `(1,5,8)` and finally `(2,6,9)`, why do you need `sort_by_key`?

Comment: Hello Jack, Sorry, I got confused, I did it wrong... I want so sum indices (0,3,6), (1,4,7) and (2,5,8). Which result is: (120), (150), (180).
That was the approach that I was doing to get the sum for the same key and storing in a vector. First, sort by key and later reduce_by_key. Is it possible to get the same vector values following a different strategy without the need of a vector holding the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original thrust example [you linked](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sum_rows.cu) performed a row-sum on an underlying data set that had row-major storage.  Your question is essentially how to do the same thing when the underlying storage is column-major.

We can use essentially the same method, but we must use permutation iterators to convert the underlying column-major storage to row-major storage "on the fly".

For this, we can borrow the functor I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990857/thrust-copy-outputiterator-column-major-order/21249149#21249149).

Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t466.cu
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 3
#define DSIZE (COLS*ROWS)
#define INIT 10
#define STEP 10

// convert a linear index to a row index
template <typename T>
struct linear_index_to_row_index : public thrust::unary_function<T,T>
{
  T C; // number of columns

  __host__ __device__
  linear_index_to_row_index(T C) : C(C) {}

  __host__ __device__
  T operator()(T i)
  {
    return i % C;
  }
};

struct rm2cm_idx_functor : public thrust::unary_function<int, int>
{
  int r;
  int c;

  rm2cm_idx_functor(int _r, int _c) : r(_r), c(_c) {};

  __host__ __device__
  int operator() (int idx)  {
    unsigned my_r = idx/c;
    unsigned my_c = idx%c;
    return (my_c * r) + my_r;
  }
};


int main(void)
{
  int C = COLS;     // number of columns
  int R = ROWS;     // number of rows
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_vals(DSIZE);
  // initialize data
  thrust::sequence(h_vals.begin(), h_vals.end(), INIT, STEP);
  thrust::device_vector<int> vals = h_vals;
  std::cout << " Initial data: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_vals.begin(), h_vals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  // allocate storage for row sums and indices
  thrust::device_vector<int> row_sums(R);
  thrust::device_vector<int> row_indices(R);

  // compute row sums by summing values with equal row indices
  thrust::reduce_by_key
    (thrust::make_permutation_iterator(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(R)), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), rm2cm_idx_functor(R, C))),
     thrust::make_permutation_iterator(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(R)) + (R*C), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), rm2cm_idx_functor(R, C)) + (R*C)),
     thrust::make_permutation_iterator(vals.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), rm2cm_idx_functor(R, C))),
     row_indices.begin(),
     row_sums.begin(),
     thrust::equal_to<int>(),
     thrust::plus<int>());

  // print data
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_row_sums = row_sums;
  std::cout << " Results: " << std::endl;
  thrust::copy(h_row_sums.begin(), h_row_sums.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t466 t466.cu
$ ./t466
 Initial data:
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,
 Results:
120,150,180,
$
```

Note that I have also changed the `linear_index_to_row_index` functor to give me a row index suitably organized for underlying *column-major* storage (the previous functor returned the index when the underlying storage was assumed to be *row-major*).  This only involved changing the division operation to a modulo operation and pass `R` instead of `C` to initialize the functor, so note the subtle difference.

Comment: Hello robert! Today, I was testing your implementation but with different row size, for instance, ROWS 4 and COLS 3. And the result had the values of 4 columns: 150,180,210,240. Instead of 3 values of the 3 columns: 220,260,400. What change is necessary to sum 3 columns and 4 rows?

Comment: Remember we are summing *rows* (when the underlying storage is *column major*).  Just like the previous algorithm, one result is produced per ROW.    If you select ROWS 4 you will get the result of summing 4 rows, which is 4 results, one per row.  Try ROWS 3 and COLS 4 if you want 3 results.  And the correct answer is 220,260,300 not 220, 260, 400

Comment: yes I already tested as you told me, thanks a lot for the explanation!